# How to Create new Contact using People API with multiple values

Tags: php, google-api, google-people-api

I want to Create New Contact with multiple emails and phone numbers

i have try with one email and phone number it is working this is the code im using

```
$name = new Google_Service_PeopleService_Name();
$name->setGivenName('00nirman');
$name->setFamilyName('weerasinghe');
$person->setNames($name);
$email1 = new Google_Service_PeopleService_EmailAddress();
$email1->setValue('test@example.com');
$person->setEmailAddresses($email1);

$phone1 = new Google_Service_PeopleService_PhoneNumber();
$phone1->setValue('0777677305');
$phone1->setType('home');
$person->setPhoneNumbers($phone1);
$exe = $people_service->people->createContact($person)->execute;
```

Can Someone help me to modify the code to push multiple values i have go true lots of google docs but i cannot fine a way to do in php

Comment: Can you not pass arrays of phone numbers, to Person::setPhoneNumbers?

Comment: i have try with this
$phone1 = new Google_Service_PeopleService_PhoneNumber(
array('value'=>'0777677305'),
 array('value'=>'0774112128')
); 

Not working

Comment: How about: `$person->setPhoneNumbers([$phone1, $phone2]);`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parogrock thank you for the answer

```
$phone1 = new Google_Service_PeopleService_PhoneNumber();
$phone2 = new Google_Service_PeopleService_PhoneNumber();
$phone1->setValue('0777677305');
$phone2->setValue('0774112128');

$person->setPhoneNumbers([$phone1,$phone2]);

$exe = $people_service->people->createContact($person)->execute;
```